# Errors when casting from Chromecast Sample App (Brain Freeze Error)

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I'm trying to program a small app for the Chrome Cast. I'm starting with the Android Sample App located on Github. The app itself works good. I can see my device on the app and connect to it, however once I connect I get a "Brain Freeze" error. The closest thing I get on screen to a description of the error is "Application Aborted", then it goes back to the "Ready to cast" screen. I tried debugging it to see if I could get more information about the error, but the closest thing to an error message I could see was a Javascript error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: loadTimeData is not defined` and an `?error=20000` somewhere in the Elements Tab of the Chrome WebDevTool.

I'm really perplexed about this error. Most likely it has something to do with the receiver code, but my code is pretty much the same as the one in the sample app. the only thing different is my AppID. Hope fully someone has come across the same error before, or can shed some light on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only "brain freeze" errors I've seen is in the JavaScript for the ChromeCast home screen. These errors seem to be related to connectivity issues. Typically something couldn't be loaded from the internet. That might indicate a networking issue for your device.

The "Uncaught ReferenceError: loadTimeData is not defined" error is due to a small bug in the ChromeCast home screen HTML. It doesn't appear to have any affect on the home screen.

Error 20000 is listed as an "aborted" error code in the home screen JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I know there shouldn't be any connectivity issues. I have no problems accessing YouTube or Netflix and I can load the receiver URL on my computer. Could it have something to do with it being an https URL?

Comment: All the testing I've done has been with HTTP receivers. I would be surprising if HTTPS isn't supported.

Comment: I think it has something to do with my certificate. I just realised that now. I'm using a free certificate from StartSSL. They should be supported on most browsers, but it might be that the Chromecast is not recognising the certificate as valid and is aborting the connection. it might be good to have better error messages, though!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your receiver is at the exact Url that you provided Google when you whitelisted your receiver.  You can test this by entering the Url in a browser on any device on your local network.

Comment: It is actually the same URL and it is accessible and has the code I uploaded. So I know that is not the issue.